# custom class not getting assigned to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, xcode6.4

I have following view controllers in my storyboard[image]

I have created two custom class, which are `RegisterViewController.swift` and `SignInViewController.swift`, when I select my `RegisterViewController` in storyboard, I can see `RegisterViewController.swift` being assigned to my `registerviewController`, but when I create new custom class called `SignInViewController.swift` and when I try to assign it to the `SignInview`, it is not getting assigned however it is appearing in my custom class dropdown, just to make sure, if I select assistant editor, I see the `RegisterViewController.swift` code but it should be showing `SignInViewController.swift` code. What I am missing here?

This how my `identity inspector` looks when I select SignInViewController
[image]

This is my `signinviewcontroller.swift`

```
import UIKit

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

//code

}
```

Comment: Can you show the class definition for `SignInView`?

Comment: So, that setting won't 'stick' when you put it in  the inspector?

Comment: Module name and project name should be same unless you are using custom Module

Comment: myproject name is `userLoginAndRegistration` @karthikPrabhu

Comment: @Paulw11 I can see the class being assigned to the SignInviewController, but on opening assistant editor, it loads the code of `registerViewController.swift`

Comment: You can change what the assistant editor opens - It is probably just set to manual instead of automatic - Make sure 'automatic' is selected next to the two circles in the assistant editor title bar